# Data structure with multiple values for key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to map above structure of the data in MySQL?
I wonder how to assign multiple values for `Tags` key.

This is an example from the CouchDB tutorial.

```
{
    "Subject": "I like Plankton",
    "Author": "Rusty",
    "PostedDate": "5/23/2006",
    "Tags": ["plankton", "baseball", "decisions"],
    "Body": "I decided today that I don't like baseball. I like plankton."
}
```

Comment: need a new table called `tag` and make foreign key to `tag` table on your (i guess) `post` table.. however things are not that simple if you have `many to many` relationship. I suggest you to resume with couchdb, no mysql..

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I found a nice [article](http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas) about many-to-many relationship in MySQL. Indeed, as @hgoz [advised](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316379/data-structure-with-multiple-values-for-key-in-mysql#comment21623546_15316379) is better to stay with CouchDB or MongoDB :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 tables, one for the items, and another one for the item tags.

Columns in table 'items':

- "SubjectID" (primary key, numeric, autoincrement)
- "Subject"
- "Author"
- "PostedDate"
- "Body"

Columns in table 'item_tags':

- 'SubjectID' (primary key, foreign key)
- 'tag' (primary key)

To populate data this way, you will first need to insert the row in the items table, then get the generated SubjectID and then use that SubjectID to insert as many tags as you want in the item_tags table.